# Count Distinct Records between a repeating record in column using BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column in table LIKE below

```
| Column A | Column B |
| Active   | 202211210423 |
|   XYZ    | 202211210424 |
|   XYZ    | 202211210424 |
...

|   PQR    | 202211210426 |
| Active   | 202211210523 |
| abc      | 202211210525 |
```

[Table_Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klul5.png)

How do I count distinct records from Column A that are between "Active"?

Output can be like, COLUMN C is distinct count between "Active".

```
| Column A | Column B     | Column C |
| Active   | 202211210423 | x
|   XYZ    | 202211210424 | 24
|   XYZ    | 202211210424 | 24
...

|   PQR    | 202211210426 | 24 
| Active   | 202211210523 | 24
| abc      | 202211210525 | y
```

[Expected_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2y7W.png)

Can we use Analytical functions to do that?

I tried using FIRST_VALUE function It did not work as they all will get to the first appearance of Active.

**Input Fields 1**

[image: Input Fields 1]

**Output 2**

[image: Output 2]

[[Dataset]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ElQIkwHD_MjPqnRP5zeN2jBi9wYIKhwZV6hsPZ1i0U/edit?usp=sharing)[5](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ElQIkwHD_MjPqnRP5zeN2jBi9wYIKhwZV6hsPZ1i0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: *Count* where *ColB* has value of `Active` are 0, 3, 1 respectively in the **output 2**. what do they mean ?

Comment: It is the count of preceding distinct Timestamp from current row = Active. The 3 counts are 2022120601310,2022120601325,2022120601342 and same for other.

Comment: Your new output example does not make sense. Please check your 2nd example. Please explain what you mean by "count distinct records from Column A". The column `ColA` has only the value "T100" and thus the distinct count is always one and not three as in the 2nd example.

Comment: Hi Samuel, the Col A you are asking is different for 2nd input and output  I have mentioned. I will get you a sample dataset and edit my previous questions. Sorry.

Comment: Hi samuel, i have added a dataset and outcome in the link 5.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I clearly understood your requirements, but you might consider below.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(agg, part),
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.timestamp) FROM t.agg x WHERE x.colB <> 'Active') Count,
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(timestamp, colB)) OVER (PARTITION BY colA, part) agg FROM (
      SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w0 - COUNTIF(colB <> 'Active') OVER w1 AS part
        FROM sample_data
      WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
             w1 AS (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    )
  ) t
 ORDER BY timestamp;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First we generate some sample data in table `tbl`.

For distinct counts, a group identifer is helpful and created as `row_group` . Then each partition is viewed individually.

```
with tbl as (select *, 1000+cast(rand()*5 as int64)+10*row_number() over () as colB from unnest(["Active","Y","X","Active","Y","Z","X","Active"])colA ),
helper as (select *, countif(colA="Active") over (order by colB rows between  unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as row_group from tbl)
select *,
-1+count(distinct colA) over (partition by row_group)
 from helper
```

For counting the total numbers, this way is easier:
Then we create a `helper` table with a row number by ordering of `colB`. The minimum and maximum of this row number has to be found for `unbounded preceding` and `unbounded following`. Substracting gives the total amount between these key words.

```sql
with tbl as (select *, 1000+cast(rand()*5 as int64)+10*row_number() over () as colB from unnest(["Active","Y","X","Active","Y","Z","X","Active"])colA ),
helper as (select *, row_number() over (order by colB) as row_id from tbl)
select *,
min(if(colA="Active",row_id,null)) over (order by colB rows between current row and unbounded following)-
ifnull(max(if(colA="Active",row_id,null)) over (order by colB rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)
 from helper
```

Comment: It did not work for me Samuel, because it is not exactly subtraction from highest to lowest, I need count between those active's. Col B does not necessarily have constant increasing numbers, i.e 424,425.... It will be like 424,426, 430 etc. in that case Max - Min will not give the correct answer.

Comment: The table `helper` creates a row number `row_id`, which increases by one. The col B does not need to have constant increasing numbers. My answer ueses random number for Col B to mimik this.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I added one more column where you can get idea of how my table looks. Please check 3rd and 4th images in the question.